# how to remove blinking of hover?

Tags: jquery, hover, mouseenter, mouseout

I used both hover and mouseenter, mouseout but both are working same.

how can i stop blinking.

**html**

```
<div class="pro_img_border">
            <div class="pro_img" id="pro_img_1">
            </div>
            <div class="pro_img-txt" id="img_1-komal">
                  hover text...
            </div>
        </div>

<div class="pro_img_border_1">
            <div class="pro_img" id="pro_img_2">
            </div>
            <div class="pro_img-txt" id="img_2-komal">
                  hover text...
            </div>
        </div>`
```

**css**

```
.pro_img_border{
        border: 1px dotted #000;
        border-radius: 150px;
        width: 221px;
        height: 221px;
        padding: 10px;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
    .pro_img{
        z-index:0;
        border-radius: 150px;
        background-color: #cccccc;
        width: 221px;
        height: 221px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: absolute;        
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .pro_img-txt{
        border-radius: 150px;
        background-color: rgba(202, 140, 140, 0.52);
        width: 221px;
        height: 221px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: absolute;
        line-height: 19;
        font-size: 20px;
        color: rgba(1, 0, 0, 1);
        display: none;
        z-index:10;
    }
```

**jquery**

```
$('.pro_img_border #pro_img_1').mouseenter(function(){
                $( "#img_1-komal" ).show();


          });
          $('.pro_img_border #pro_img_1').mouseleave(function() {
                  $('#img_1-komal').hide();

        });

$('.pro_img_border_1 #pro_img_2').hover(function(){
                $( "#img_2-komal" ).show();


          }, function() {
                  $('#img_2-komal').hide();

        });
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/d91u1xd0/1/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.pro_img_border').mouseenter(function(){
            $( "#img_1-komal" ).show();


      });
      $('.pro_img_border').mouseleave(function() {
              $('#img_1-komal').hide();

    });
```

Comment: why do u used parent element? Is there any other solution with child element?

Comment: because while you show that second div the hover or moveleave event are triggered auto because the previous div will be below the new div and your move is now pointing to new/second div

There can be but, the mouse event will trigger as soon as the cursor will point the new div